# Function that does for Map what Through does for Apply?

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

`Through` allows multiple functions to be easily applied to a single argument.  For instance, suppose I wanted to count the number of characters in `{"t", "o", "d", "a", "y"}`, and also join them into a single string.  Then I could do:

```
s1 = {"t", "o", "d", "a", "y"}
Through[{StringJoin, Length}[#]]& @ s1
```

> {today, 5}

But suppose I wanted to do this for a list of lists.   Then I would need to use `Map` to apply the functions to each sublist. I could accomplish that with this:

```
s2 = {{"h", "e", "l", "l", "o"}, {"d", "a", "y"}}
Thread@ MapThread[# /@ s2 &, {{StringJoin, Length}}]
```

> {{hello, 5}, {day, 3}}

But that syntax is a bit ugly.  It would be simpler and more elegant if there were a function that could do for `Map` what `Through` does for `Apply`, i.e. that allowed one to directly `Map` multiple functions to a single argument, like so (here I've called  the hypothetical function `MultiMap`):

```
MultiMap[{StringJoin, Length}[#]]& @ s2
```

> {{hello, 5}, {day, 3}}

Does such a function exist?

Comment: `{StringJoin[##], Length[{##}]} & @@@ s2`

Comment: @Acus  That's nice, and I'll keep it in mind, but it lacks the essential feature of Through, which is that it allows one to apply two different functions to a single argument, rather than having to repeat the argument for each function.

Comment: `Through[{StringJoin, Length}[{##}]] & @@@ s2`

Comment: @Acus Very nice, thanks!

Comment: @Acus, please convert your comments into a more detailed answer.

Comment: Why not just `Through[{StringJoin, Length}[#]]&/@s2` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ClearAll[mapThrough]
mapThrough[a_List] := Map[Through @ a @ ## &]
```

or, as suggested by J.M. in comments,

```
mapThrough[a_] := Map @ Through @* a
```

or

```
mapThrough = a |-> Map @ Through @* a
```

***Examples:***

```
s2 = {{"h", "e", "l", "l", "o"}, {"d", "a", "y"}};

mapThrough[{StringJoin, Length}] @ s2
```

> ```
> {{"hello", 5}, {"day", 3}}
> ```

Use with an arbitrary list of functions:

```
mapThrough[{StringReverse @* StringJoin, Reverse, First, Last, #[[{1, -1}]&}] @ s2
```

> ```
> {{"olleh", {"o", "l", "l", "e", "h"}, "h", "o", {"h", "o"}},
>  {"yad", {"y", "a", "d"}, "d", "y", {"d", "y"}}}
> ```

Comment: I use the following variation myself rather frequently: `Through @* {StringJoin, Length} /@ {{"h", "e", "l", "l", "o"}, {"d", "a", "y"}}`

Comment: @J.M. I think you should post this as an answer, I really like operator forms that avoid using slots.

Comment: @Carl, this is effectively equivalent to kglr's approach (with the advantage you mention of being slot-free), so I would prefer that kglr edit his answer to include it.

Comment: @J.M. I found all the answers here great—and instructive. But I have to say yours was my favorite, because it accomplishes the task with the simplest possible syntax: Going from "multiApply" to "multiMap" just requires changing from `Through[{func1, func2, func3...}[s2]]` to `Through@*{func1, func2, func3...}/@s2`.  And it cleverly accomplishes this by composing func 1, func2,.. with `Through`to create a new composite function, and then mapping that composite function to the arguments. Since you donated your syntax to kglr's answer, I'll give it the credit :).

Answer (score 18):

One option is to use the forking operator `{fn1, fn2, ...}` from the [Query](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) sublanguage:

```
Query[All, {StringJoin, Length}][s2]

(* {{hello,5},{day,3}} *)
```

Answer (score 12):

First, the shortcut `@@@` is equivalent to "Map Apply" or simply speaking apply to level 1:

```
Apply[f, {{1, 2}, {a, b}}, {1}]
```

> {f[1, 2], f[a, b]}

```
f@@@{{1, 2}, {a, b}}
```

> {f[1, 2], f[a, b]}

Second, `{##}` takes all arguments and puts into `List` on which then pure function `f = Through[{StringJoin, Length}[#]]&` is applied. In general you can imagine functional programming like an engineering line conveyor which produces something you want from elementary operations.

Answer (score 5):

Use the operator form of `Map` and new-in-14.0 `Comap`:

```
Map[Comap@{StringJoin, Length}]@s2
(* {{"hello", 5}, {"day", 3}} *)
```

[image]